# How to modify the template of .pro in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, c++11, qt-creator

I want to modify the template of .pro in Qt Creator, because each time I have to add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` in .pro.

Could someone please tell me how to modify the template of it? I don't know which file to modify. I use gcc 4.8.1, with qt5 in ubuntu 13.10.

I'm really new to programming. Thanks in advance for any answer. (Please forgive me for my poor English...)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a custom wizard and play with it's settings. Take a look here for more information:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-project-wizards.html